# Manipulating a value in a Maybe

Tags: haskell, functor, option-type

A function in some code I'm writing returns

```
Just 3
```

What I'd like is to remove the Just and manipulate 3 as I please.

I must confess to not understanding the Just syntax, but while I work that out, I'd appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Just 3` has type `Maybe Int`.  You can either manipulate the int *within* the `Maybe`, the simplest form of that being `fmap`, e.g.

```
ghci> fmap (\x -> x + 1) (Just 3) 
Just 4
```

which preserves the structure of the `Maybe` type, that is to say, it preserves `Nothing`s

```
ghci> fmap (\x -> x + 1) Nothing
Nothing
```

Or you can define a function which pattern matches:

```
doThing :: Maybe Int -> String
doThing (Just x) = "I got " ++ show x
doThing Nothing  = "I didn't get anything"

ghci> doThing (Just 3)
"I got 3"
```

There is also a useful function called `fromMaybe` (defined in `Data.Maybe`):

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
```

It will extract the value from a `Maybe`, but you have to provide it with what to return if it turned out to be `Nothing`:

```
ghci> import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
ghci> fromMaybe 0 (Just 3)
3
ghci> fromMaybe 0 Nothing
0
```

Note that in all of these cases, we have to decide what to do if the value is `Nothing`, which is the essential feature of the `Maybe` type.

Answer (score 3):

If I give you a recipe for chocolate cake, you can't take off the recipe and just eat the cake as you see fit. You first have to follow the recipe.

Similarly, if I give you a `Maybe Int`, you can't just take off the `Maybe` and manipulate the `Int`; you must first inspect it to see whether you got `Just` an `Int` you can manipulate or `Nothing`.

The most fundamental way to perform this inspection, which all other techniques use, is pattern matching. The `fromMaybe` function luqui suggests will serve as a good example. It turns a `Maybe a` into an `a`, using the given default if it finds `Nothing`.

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
fromMaybe def (Just val) = val
fromMaybe def Nothing = def
```

Pro tip: as you go through the process of learning Haskell, you will find several good opportunities to think back on the parable of the cake.

Comment: Indeed, wise one. To eat my cake, I must have it! :)

Comment: Shouldn't the last equation return `def` rather than `Nothing`?

Answer (score 1):

Another function that might be useful, and which is actually in the `Prelude`, is

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

which is very similar to `fromMaybe` but lets you use a function to work on the variable inside your `Just` instead (you need to give a default that matches the type of the output of the function for if you have `Nothing`). Example:

```
maybeShow = maybe "Got nothing..." show

maybeShow $ Just 3  -- gives "3"
maybeShow $ Nothing -- gives "Got nothing..."
```

And then there is a function which the other answerers seem to have strategically avoided :) But I think it should be here for completeness:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
```

which takes a value out of its `Just` wrapper. The problem with this function is it's a partial function, i.e. it's not defined for `Nothing` values:

```
fromJust $ Just 3  -- gives 3
fromJust $ Nothing -- gives *** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

so as you can see this function is kind of risky to use and it's definitely not a clean solution. Still, if you're *sure* you will not get `Nothing`, or if you're just playing around and you want to get rid of annoying `Maybe`s, it can be very useful in practice.

Comment: Yes, it was strategic :).  Note that in the pure subset of Haskell (the best part ;), exceptions can not be caught, so getting this one wrong means your whole program crashes.  Also the error message is crap, no indication as to where and under what conditions is crashed.